# Puppeteer page.waitforNavigation not working in 1.8?

Tags: puppeteer

I am having trouble getting puppeteer to wait for navigation.

According to the docs [Here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) the example is:

```
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(), // The promise resolves after navigation has finished
  page.click('a.my-link'), // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
]);
```

My code is:

```
const element = await page.waitForXPath(`${lineSelector.xpath}//a[contains(text(), 'Go')]`)

const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(),
  element.click()
]);
```

Everything works.. except it doesn't wait for navigation. I have tried all the different options:

- load - consider navigation to be finished when the load event is
  fired.
- domcontentloaded - consider navigation to be finished when the
  DOMContentLoaded event is fired.
- networkidle0 - consider navigation
  to be finished when there are no more than 0 network connections for
  at least 500 ms.
- networkidle2 - consider navigation to be finished
  when there are no more than 2 network connections for at least 500
  ms.

I have even tried flipping them the other way , pausing before in case something needed to resolve.

It is not actually "navigating" to another page , but it is doing client side requests to load part of the page , but I figured that netowrk monitoring ( idle or not ) - should pick up this sort of thing.

I can't rely on a selector change or dom mutation because they could be exactly the same from one click to the next.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is not actually "navigating" to another page , but it is doing client side requests to load part of the page , but I figured that netowrk monitoring ( idle or not ) - should pick up this sort of thing.

Well, no! The `waitForNavigation` means exactly what it says. It waits for navigation. So you cannot expect it to behave some other way.

It will act like that when,

- there is a navigation (not the URL change, but the actual navigation request)
- there is usage of history api.

If you want to watch ajax requests, you can use

- [page.waitForRequest(urlOrPredicate, options)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforrequesturlorpredicate-options)
- [page.waitForResponse(urlOrPredicate, options)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options)

Both has similar method to monitor the ajax request. It can either be a string or a function.

Here is how to implement this,

```
await page.waitForRequest(request => request.url() === 'http://example.com' && request.method() === 'GET');
```

Which will wait for a request that has the url specified. You can use any kind of verification as needed.